# How to use apoc.path.subgraphAll procedure in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am doing a project in which I am required to return the path or nodes in a path from a particular start node. I pass the start node to the query, and need to continue down the path until the value of the relationship property `Action` between two consecutive nodes is "ODC". Or, if the `Action` value is "ODSN", I have to break from the particular path and return the next node alone separately. I am required to process all the paths from a particular start node in this manner.

I tried using the `apoc.path.subgraphAll` procedure but did not get the desired result:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {customer_id: 4})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(c, {
relationshipFilter: ">",
minLevel: 1
})
YIELD nodes, relationships
UNWIND relationships as rel
WITH nodes, rel
WHERE rel.Action = 'ODC'
RETURN DISTINCT nodes
```

Is there another method to approach this or should I be using another APOC procedure?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to find paths containing just outgoing relationships in which only the last relationship has the `Action` value of either 'ODC' or 'ODSN'. If the value is 'ODC', then you want all the nodes in the path returned, else you only want the last node.

That use case does not need to use APOC. For example:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[rels1 *0..8]->()-[rel2:Action]->(n)
WHERE rel2.Action IN ['ODC', 'ODSN'] AND NONE(r1 IN rels1 WHERE r1.Action IN ['ODC', 'ODSN'])
WITH rel2.Action AS action, c, rels1, n
RETURN action, CASE action WHEN 'ODC' THEN [c] + [r2 IN rels1 | ENDNODE(r2)] + n ELSE [n] END AS nodes
```

Since it is best practice to put a reasonable upper bound on [variable length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#variable-length-relationships) patterns (to avoid taking too long or running out of memory), this query searches paths up to 9 (i.e., 8 + 1) relationships deep (adjust as necessary to suit your actual data).

If `action` is 'ODC', then all the nodes in the path are returned in the `nodes` list, else the list contains only the last node.

Comment: this answer you provided is a different and helpful approach to the problem ,but it is not exactly the result that i need.I have to check the relationship property at each step and decide to proceed or not based on the value of the property .I have explained it with the help of a diagram in the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77756246/in-neo4j-how-do-i-iteratively-traverse-the-nodes-and-relationships-paths-obtaine