# In Neo4j how do i iteratively traverse the nodes and relationships paths obtained from the startnode till particular relationship property is reached?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Consider I have to obtain all the nodes in the subgraph of `n:Customer` with `customer_id = 4`. Starting from this node i have to traverse each node in the path originating with `n` and break or stop traversing down the path when a relationship with `Action` property is set to `ODC`. Each relationship has the property `Action` with value either `ODC` or `ODSN`.

[image]

After breaking from one path I have to check the other paths originating from this node `n`. I have to repeat this process till all paths are traversed and return the relevant nodes.
In the image I have provided I have expanded two paths out of the 14 nodes connected to `n:Customer` (blue node). Each of the purple nodes connected to the blue can be further expanded similar to the other two paths.

I am required to store these nodes in a data structure in Java.
Any guidance on how to approach this would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: You need to greatly clarify your question. For example: 1. Do "break" and "stop" mean different things? 2. What exactly do you want to do when the value is 'ODC' versus 'ODSN'? 3. Is _every_ relationship supposed to be tested, or just the ones connected to any `Customer` node, or just the ones connected to the starting `Customer` (assuming we can encounter other `Costumers` while expanding)? Also, it would be helpful to provide sample data with expected results, along with the queries you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Neo4j 5.9+**

To return the subgraph up to but excluding any nodes beyond any relationships with `Action = 'ODC'`:

```sql
MATCH (:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r WHERE r.Action <> 'ODC']-*(n)
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

To return the subgraph up to and *including* those nodes:

```sql
MATCH path = (:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r WHERE r.Action <> 'ODC']-*
               ()-[{Action: 'ODC'}]-()
UNWIND nodes(path) AS n
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

**For Neo4j < 5.9**

To return the subgraph up to but excluding any nodes beyond any relationships with `Action = 'ODC'`:

```sql
MATCH (:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r*0..]-(n)
WHERE all(rel IN r WHERE rel.Action <> 'ODC')
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

To return the subgraph up to and *including* those nodes:

```sql
MATCH path = (:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r*0..]-()-[{Action: 'ODC'}]-()
WHERE all(rel IN r WHERE rel.Action <> 'ODC')
UNWIND nodes(path) AS n
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.I have tweaked the above query to the following to make it compatible to my version as follows

MATCH (customer:Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r*]->(n)-[relation]->(m)
WHERE ALL(relt IN r WHERE relt.Action = 'ODC')
RETURN DISTINCT customer, n ,m
the above query gives the desired output.
The query you have provided gave me the following error 

Quantified path patterns are not yet supported. (line 1, column 41 (offset: 40))
"MATCH path = (Customer {customer_id: 4})-[r WHERE r.Action <> 'ODC']-*"

Comment: Are quantified paths only supported by version 5.9?The version in my system is 5.3 version

Comment: Yes, quantified path patterns are available from 5.9 onwards. I have added pre-5.9 compatible queries to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pre-5.9 compatible queries.Will the the 5.9 compatible queries have any time efficiency advantage over the pre-5.9 compatible versions?

Comment: In this particular case, because the predicate can be applied per relationship, there should be no significant difference in performance. The advantage is just greater cohesion of variable declaration and its dependent predicate.